# React Authentication session management

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am working on this two-part application (React + Express... + Apollo (for GraphQL)). 
In order to manage authentication I have been reading guides and watching videos and I made some progress using [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) and [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) like:

1. Whenever the an user logins, React makes a request to Express with **gql** (powered by [apollo-boost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-boost)).
2. Express server (backend) sends it response back processing its data with a resolver:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
import { User } from '../models/User';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default {
  Query: {
    login: async (_, { email, password }, {req}) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('User don\'t exist');
        }

        const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isEqual) {
          throw new Error('Wrong credentials');
        }

        const {
          JWTSECRET = 'secret'
        } = process.env;

        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, email: user.email }, JWTSECRET, {
          expiresIn: '1h'
        });

        return {
          userId: user.id,
          token,
          tokenExpiration: 3600000 // Date.now()+3600000 doesn't work cause Int is 32-bit signed
        }

      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
};

const hashPassword = async password => {
  const saltRounds = 10;

  const hashedPassword = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(hash);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    }
  });

  return hashedPassword;
};
```

3. React get the response and attach it to the context and I guess it also assign some `localStorage` stuff to persist session like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import AuthContext from './auth-context';
import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

function getClient() {
    return new ApolloClient({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000/ws', credentials: 'same-origin' });
}

const AuthState = props => {
    const defaultValue = {
        userId: null,
        userFirstName: null,
        userLastName: null,
        userEmail: null,
        token: null,
        tokenExpiration: null,
        createdOn: null,
        errors: [],
        login,
        get,
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={defaultValue}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );

    /**
     * Login
     * @param {string} email 
     * @param {string} password 
     */
    async function login(email, password) {
        const client = getClient();
        const CHECK_CREDENTIALS = gql`
            query {
                login(email: "${email}", password: "${password}") {
                    userId
                    token
                    tokenExpiration
                }
            }
        `;
        const { data, loading, errors } = await client.query({
            query: CHECK_CREDENTIALS,
            errorPolicy: 'all'
        });

        if (loading) {
            defaultValue.message = "Validating credentials";
        }

        if (errors) {
            defaultValue.errors = errors.map(error => <p>{error.message}</p>);
        }

        if (data && data.login) {
            defaultValue.userId = data.login.userId;
            defaultValue.token = data.login.token;
            defaultValue.tokenExpiration = data.login.tokenExpiration;
            // Persist session ?
            localStorage.setItem('user-token', data.login.token);
            localStorage.setItem('user-token-expiration', data.login.tokenExpiration);
        }
    }

    async function get(userId) {
        const client = getClient();
        const GET_USER = gql`
            query {
                user(_id: "${userId}") {
                    firstName
                    lastName
                    email
                }
            }
        `;

        const { data, loading, errors } = await client.query({
            query: GET_USER,
            errorPolicy: 'all'
        });

        if (loading) {
            defaultValue.message = "Getting user";
        }

        if (errors) {
            defaultValue.errors = errors.map(error => <p>{error.message}</p>);
        }

        if (data && data.user) {
            defaultValue.userFirstName = data.user.firstName;
            defaultValue.userLastName = data.user.lastName;
            defaultValue.userEmail = data.user.email;
        }
    }
}

export default AuthState;
```

4. In every component that needs authentication I check for `context.token` and `context.tokenExpiration` and redirects to login or let them go through.

I have been wondering what if I set manually using Developer Console to set some `user-token` and `user-token-expiration`? What am I missing?

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: does your code work?

Comment: @Peter, I didn't try yet with `localStorage` management, but if don't use it it works until I reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I have been digging into the code and I verified that `login` resolver uses the secret signature to valitate the token.

```js
login: async (_, { email, password }, {req}) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error('wrong credentials');
    }

    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isEqual) {
      throw new Error('wrong credentials');
    }

    const {
      JWTSECRET = 'secret'
    } = process.env;

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, email: user.email }, JWTSECRET, {
      expiresIn: '1h'
    }); 

    return {
      userId: user.id,
      token,
      tokenExpiration: Date.now() + 3600000
    }

  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
}
```

In order to see in that in action go to [JWT.IO Official page](http://jwt.io) after the token is generated and paste it there. Then insert the "secret" or whatever goes there in the **Verify signature** field and it will change **Invalid signature** to **Verified**.